# Google Play Saved Games can not sync snapshot to other devices, and lost after changing device's language

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I want to add a cloud backup / restore function to my app, so I checked the Google Play Saved Games function to see if it can work. 
The code I used was the example of Google Play Saved Game - Collect All The Stars 2, you can find it here: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/CollectAllTheStars2

I have been working on it for several weeks, I can save(backup) and load snapshot on 1 device. But I meet issues below recently:

save a snapshot on the CollectAllTheStars2, change android device's language, return to CollectAllTheStars2, can not load the snapshot saved previously

save a snapshot on the CollectAllTheStars2 on device A, use device B with the same Google Account and same language, open CollectAllTheStars2, load snapshot, can not find the snapshot saved on device A

Before I do the testing, I have done the configurations like:

enable saved games support for the CollectAllTheStars2 in the Google Play Console

add testing account for the CollectAllTheStars2

It should be noticed that I only make the CollectAllTheStars2 as alpha test or internal test in Google Play Console, but not really published. But I think this should not be the real cause of this problem.
I searched on google and found that many users claimed that some other games can not sync the game progress on different devices or other issue, I doubt that the "Saved Games" function of Google Play is really robust enough? Else I many need to implement our own backup/restore game data...

Comment: I'm having similar issues, what did you do in the end?

Comment: @SimonCrane I gave up this function at that time, but I will do it later

Answer (score 0):

- save a snapshot on the CollectAllTheStars2 on device A, use device B
  with the same Google Account and same language, open
  CollectAllTheStars2, load snapshot, can not find the snapshot saved
  on device A

I faced the same problem today and solved it at last.

One of the devices (the source device: A)'s backup setting was not appropriate. **System > Backup > Advanced settings > Back up using mobile or metered Wi-Fi data** was turned off. Once I turned it on, Google Drive was synched immediately. Then the snapshot became accessible from the other device B.

[image: screenshot]

So I would suggest you to make sure whether your devices' backup setting is appropriate in addition to those Play Console settings and Play Games Services Saved Games API usages.